# What does this damaged inscription in a church say?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, ecclesiastical-latin, inscription

I've been sent the following photo of an inscription in a Unitarian church.

[image: Low-res photo]

As best I can tell, it says:

> Templum hoc [re]novat[u]m
>   est […]eribus denuo et inte[g]re[?]
>   regnante serenissimo dono do[…]o
>   principe Georgio Rakoci
>   Anno do[min]i 1640

In other words, this church was renovated once by ??? and again by a gift from the most serene reigning prince, George Rákóczi.

However, I'm curious what the other damaged parts might mean. What was the cause of the first renovation? And what is the word starting with *D* on the third line?

Comment: D for Domino using the conventional tilde for a missing n or m plus vowel.

Comment: @Hugh Ah, so most serene reigning _lord_ prince?

Comment: Could *denuo* mean 'anew, from scratch;' and *integre* (almost the same) 'totally, from the ground up.'

Comment: The Brill edition is (in brief) "Title: Instructio, quam ... princeps ac dominus, dominus Georgius Rakoci, Transylvaniae princeps, partium regni Hungariae dominus et Siculorum comes etcaet. tradidit ... domino Georgio Rakoci, filio suo, natu maiori non longe post cum ille scholis valedixisset"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_I_R%C3%A1k%C3%B3czi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With some help from [this description](http://www.adatbank.ro/inchtm.php?akod=3878), which contains a few errors, here's what I think it says:

> Templum hoc r[e]novatum
>   est [l]ateribus denuo et integre
>   regnante serenissimo do[mi]no do[mi]no
>   principe Georgio Rakoci
>   Anno do[mini] 1640

My translation:

> This temple [i.e. church] was completely and newly renovated with bricks during the reign of the most serene lord, the lord prince [George I Rákóczi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_I_R%C3%A1k%C3%B3czi) in A.D. 1640.

<del>It seems that "Dominus, Dominus noster" (the lord, our lord...) is an idiom. Searching for ["domino domino nostro"](https://www.google.com/search?q="domino+domino+nostro") returns numerous examples. I'm not positive that it should be parsed out that way, instead of just a simple second "domino," but the line over the "n" (and some superficial experience with paleography) makes me suspect that "nostro" is intended.</del>

On second thought, I agree with Cerberus's comment that "Domino" is repeated twice, first with "serenissimo" and second as part of his title. Such repetition of "Dominus" seems to be fairly common.

Comment: I think this is mostly correct. I wonder why you translate *lateribus* as "with bricks": is that Neolatin? Isn't something like "sides" or "side aisles" intended? // Dominus can indeed be repeated; I believe one is the ordinary polite form of address, the other an address belonging to certain titles. I have often seen this repeated use.

Comment: While the abbreviations are indeed unconventional, (*dono* rather than *dno*), I would not be inclined to believe in the second *dono*'s being *do no* "domino nostro". I rather think there is a line above both instances of *dono*; the line above the first one might seem like the tail of the t above, but notice that none of his other t's have tails. So I would read it simply as *do[mi]no do[mi]no* without *nostro*.

Comment: @Cerberus I agree with your second point. As for the first, I was taking it as [*later, -is*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlater) (not *latus*!) That seems to make most sense in context.

Comment: Ah! I must confess I did not even remember the existence of this word. Good.

Answer (score 2):

It could be "dono" which would mean "by gift"
Donum fed into most Romance languages, and would make sense to be placed here to show the king helped out of generosity

Templum hoc r[e]novatum
est [l]ateribus denuo et integre
regnante serenissimo dono do[mi]no
principe Georgio Rakoci
Anno do[mini] 1640

This temple was fully rebuilt with bricks
By gift of the lord, while Georgio Rakoci reigned most peacefully
In the year of our lord 1640

Dono might look out of place, but if serenissimo is applied to the reign instead of to the king it makes perfect sense